# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space al arrancar weblogic

Tags: weblogic

estoy intentando arrancar un weblogic en eclipse, pero al arrancarlo me da un error en la memoria de java. Este es uno de ellos:
Exception in thread "Timer-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

He intentado cambiar la memoria desde java, desde el fichero eclipse.ini, desde la configuracion de argumentos de java, desde la consola del weblogic... Y no he podido hacerlo, alguna ayuda al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

Un error frecuente es considerar la PermGen como parte del Heap, es decir, que está dentro de los parámetros -Xms y -Xmx. Y no. La PermGen utiliza la ram nativa y es independiente a la heap de Java. Y esto es así hasta la 1.7 de Java. A partir de la 1.8, la PermGen no se gestiona a parte como en las versiones anteriores, es decir con el flag PermGen. Por ejemplo, si tienes un servidor de aplicaciones con Jenkins, necesitarias configurar los parámetros Xms y Xmx y el PermGen (usando java 1.7). Si el servidor necesita 4 Gb de Heap y PermGen de 2Gb, el total consumido por este servidor es de 6Gb Ram.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar ¿La aplicacion que intentas levantar es muy pesada? ¿La has levantado antes?

1. Si es muy pesada para levantarla tienes que aumentar la memoria al servidor desde eclipse. OJO!! Aumentar la memoria de arranque, no la del eclipse.ini
2. Si la has levantado antes y ahora no te levanta puede ser que weblogic, por alguna razón, no te haya borrado los ficheros temporales que genera. Desde el eclipse elimina la aplicacion e intenta arrancar weblogic limpio. Fíjate si en la carpeta de temporales sigues tu aplicacion (o cualquier otra que hayas levantado), si es así, elimínala y también la entrada del fichero config.xml de weblogic (En este fichero busca las etiquetas `<app-deployment>` que contenga tu apliación).
3. Si el error te da ejecutando la aplicacion una vez levantada solo  te queda añadir mas memoria a weblogic, desde la consola o directamente en el config.xml.

Comment: He modificado la memoria ya, pero me sigue sin dejar, un compalero usa la masima aplicacion y tenemos la misma configuracion de memoria, pero a mi no me deja arrancar el weblogic.

Comment: ¿Has mirado los temporales? ¿Podrías describir cual es tu configuración y que parametros has modificado?

Comment: Si, estan borrados, he probado con la version anterior de eclipse, la mars 2

Comment: Probando con la version mars 2, tampoco me funciona.... mismo error

Comment: La versión del eclipse no es ningún problema yo he levantado weblogic con  mars y neon, por favor revisa la configuración que te he dicho antes o detalla mas tu modificaciones ya que así no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: He cambiado la memoria, el fichero eclipse.ini, el config.xml del weblogic... Y nada, he probado con 2GB de memoria, y tampoco :S

Comment: Añádele memoria al arranque del servidor de weblogic, eso no se configura en el eclipse.ini

Comment: eso se configura en el setDomainEnv.cmd si no me confundo no?, ya lo tengo cambiado tambien.

Comment: Eso se modifica en las opciones de arranque del servidor (Open Launch configuration)

Comment: Donde puedo encontrar eso? He estado mirando pero no lo encuentro

Comment: ¿que versión de WebLogic estas usando? ¿cuanta ram tiene tu maquina? ¿que versión de Java usas? y ¿que valores tienes en los parametros de inicialización?